# Alternative definition of Hardy spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

Classically, Hardy spaces $H^p$on the disk are introduced as set of  functions analytic on $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$, which has bounded $H^p$ norm:
$$ \|f\|_{H^p} = \sup_{0\leq r < 1} \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(r \, e^{\mathrm{i} \theta})|^p \, d \theta \right)^{1/p}, \text { for } 1 < p \leq  \infty, \quad \|f\|_{H^\infty} = \sup_{z \in \mathbb{D}} |f(z)| .$$

Now for the case $p=\infty$ the $\|\cdot\|_{H^\infty}$ norm coincides with $\sup_{|z|=1} |f(z)|$ for all analytic functions on $\mathbb{D}$ (due to the maximum modulus principle).

Also, for $p<\infty$ and it can be shown for $f \in H^p$ (see e.g. the book by Duren)
$$ \|f\|_{H^p} = \sup_{0\leq r < 1} \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(r \, e^{\mathrm{i} \theta})|^p \, d \theta \right)^{1/p} =  \lim_{ r \rightarrow 1} \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(r \, e^{\mathrm{i} \theta})|^p \, d \theta \right)^{1/p} = \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f( \, e^{\mathrm{i} \theta})|^p \, d \theta \right)^{1/p}. \quad (*)$$

Shouldn't it be possible to define the Hardy spaces rightaway as those analytic functions in $\mathbb{D}$ that have bounded $L_p$ norm on $\{|z|=1\}$, i.e. $(*) \leq \infty$.?

If yes, can you give me a reference where this definition is used?

Comment: No, because there are analytic functions on the disc that have modulus $1$ a.e. on the boundary and grow like crazy inside. Example: $\exp [(1+z)/(1-z)].$

Comment: I should also add: What is this $f(e^{it})$ you speak of? $f$ is only defined in the open disc. Well, you prove that there is a boundary function (a.e.), but it's not clear at the outset that there is. The classical definition is used in a big way to get there.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i dont understand your example.. your functions modulus is bounded by 1 on $\mathbb{D}$, isn't it?

Comment: sure, the classical definition makes sense. but I wonder wether this simplified definition is equivalent to the classical with the $\sup$.
(and if this has been pointed out somewhere in the literature).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $f(z) = \exp{(1+z)/(1-z)}.$ This function has modulus $1$ on the boundary except at $1.$ So therefore $f\in H^\infty?$ Hardly. Look at $f(r)$ as $r\to 1^-.$

Comment: thanks for this answer. but on the circle $|z|=1$ your function $f$ it not in $L^\infty$. Therefore it does not belong to $H^\infty$ either. so why is this a counter example?

Comment: $|f(e^{it})| = 1, 0<t<2\pi.$ Therefore $f(e^{it})\in L^\infty.$

Answer (score 2):

Any counterexample for $p=\infty$ is automatically a counterexample for all $p>0$. You have $f$ which is not $H^\infty$, but which has boundary values in $L^\infty$. Hence the boundary values are in $L^p$. And hence $f$ is not in $H^p$, because of the result that says if $f$ is in $H^p$ and the boundary values are in $L^\infty$ then $f$ is in $H^\infty$.

Comment: I found this reference. is the definition in the first few lines  a mistake than? 
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01214309

Comment: @User133713 Yes, the definition there is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative definition of $H^{p}(D)$ for $1 \le p \le\infty$ is as the set of $f \in L^{p}(\mathbb{T})$ for which
$$
            \int_{0}^{2\pi}f(e^{it})e^{int}dt=0,\;\;\; n = 1,2,3,\cdots.
$$
The Poisson integral of $f$ then gives a function $F$ that (a) is holomorphic in $D$ because of the absence of the above terms; and (b) has the required boundary continuity that comes from the Poisson integral. That's very close to what you want.